# free galley snacks and asking

Tags: air-travel, long-haul

I just saw [an article in *The Independent*](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/british-airways-snacks-free-prices-food-menu-long-haul-economy-ba-a7447686.html) that states

> British Airways has scrapped the long-established option for economy passengers to ask for free snacks between meals on intercontinental flights.… Previously, peckish passengers were able to ask staff in the galley for items such as crisps or chocolate. The “raid the larder” arrangement still exists in Club World, but economy travellers must now either bring food on board or buy items such as Pringles (£1.80) or Maltesers (£3.20).

I didn't know that you could go to the galley and ask for snacks. Does anybody know what sorts of snacks can one ask for— fruits or is it limited to only confectionery only? Also is there a protocol/rule that is and should be followed while requesting some? This is specifically for long-haul flights (in excess of +6 hour flights).

Comment: I assume most of the snacks are pretzels or candies or things like that (I would be surprised if there was fresh fruits (at least for economy class). And there is nothing wrong in asking for some snacks.

Comment: We had apples on a Cathay Pacific flight to Hong-Kong. I think this is airline-dependent and thus maybe unanswerable though.

Comment: It never hurts to ask, but the answer may be anything from "we don't have anything" to "you can buy this for a few dollars" to "here's a bin of goodies, knock yourself out" depending on the airline and the route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically what ever snacks they offer when bringing the drink cart through the aisles is what they offer as on request snacks.

Occasionally on really long haul (10 hour plus) flights, the airline may make available a mini-sandwich (bun with cheese and wilted lettuce) or something else more substantial than just pretzels and peanuts, as an on request snack.

There is no time table for this, it is available most anytime the cabin crew is not serving the passengers.  Some airlines put snacks out for you to take as you please, others you have to ask the cabin crew.

Most every full service airline offers this on their flights, but they rarely announce it or publicize it.  If you ask for a second drink or some more snacks they are happy to set you up, but they don't want to serve the entire plane another round because they don't have an unlimited supply.

Answer (score 7):

Very depending on the Airline, as a rule of thumb I would say "A mini-package of anything" - gummy bears, pretzel, big variety of chocolates etc. I know no protocol/rule, but if they offer such snacks being polite and asking not for multiple items at once (e.g. 5 chocolate bars) always worked for me. 
In fact sometimes I felt the staff is happy to do something and not waiting until their shift finishes and they can have some sleep. 
Btw. same applies to drinks. E.g. Flying with Singapur Airlines is quite awesome. They offered 4 different cocktails, beer, wine, water, softdrinks etc. etc.

Comment: I was offered alcoholic drinks which didn't taste great, maybe something to do with altitude but this was during servicing everybody (Qatar Airways). I'm asking outside the service window.